# "None" Prints on the end of the print command

Tags: python, arrays, function

```
def Tempurature(Lowest, Highest):
ok = False
while not ok:
    try:
       Input = int(input(print("\nEnter the Mid-Day tempurature for Day {}:".format(Counter))))
       if Input >= Lowest and Input <= Highest:
            ok = True
            return Input
       else:
            print ("Please enter a valid number between {} and {}".format(Lowest, Highest))
    except:
        print ("Please enter a number")
```

So this is my Function, I use it to input numbers into an array like so

```
Counter = int(1)
TempDay = array.array ("i", range(31))
TempDay[Counter] = (Tempurature(-90, 60))
```

However when I call up the function, the following prints

```
Enter the Mid-Day tempurature for Day 1:
None
```

Any solutions on how to get rid of the "None" print to make the input line at the ":" rather than at the end of the "None"?

Comment: try remove print in the input function

Comment: also, just for programming convention: variables, parameters, and functions (or methods if you call them that) should start with lowercase letters. Classes should start with upper case letters. If someone else were to read your code (if it were a complex program) they might get confused if they are reading over it quickly. Not a big thing though.

Answer (score 0):

Ditch the `print` call inside of your `input` function.  `input` will automatically print anything inside of the `input` call.

```
Input = int(input("\nEnter the Mid-Day tempurature for Day {}:".format(Counter))))
```

The reason it's printing `None` is due to the `print` call; after its completion it returns `None`, and since `input` will happily print whatever you give it while blocking for input, it's printing the `None` as if you had intended to do that.

Answer (score -1):

You are calling [.format](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#format) with a `None` argument.

The variable `Counter` is not available inside your [function scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules).

Also, you are actually calling `input()` on the *return* of `print()`, you need to pass in the string to `input()`.

Comment: It could be defined outside of the function.  Also, if it were defined to `None`, then you'd see, "Enter the Mid-Day tempurature for Day None" instead.  They see a number there, so that's not an issue.

Comment: As I mention in my answer, based on the code as given, `Counter` inside the function scope.

I do also give the same response as yours regarding the return of print being passed to input. Please do not downvote answers which actually solve the issue just because you also have a pending answer.

Comment: I'm not downvoting it because I've also made an answer.  I'm downvoting it because the first two parts of your answer have nothing to do with the actual problem.

Comment: I saw two errors in his code, I answered something which solves both the queried error and another one which he will shortly experience. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes.  I told you already.  `Counter` is not `None`, and you wouldn't see the same output if it *was*.  Why don't you try it and see?